# c++ remove non utf8

Tags: c++, utf-8

I am working to validate that a string is utf8. 
I have found method [g_utf8_validate](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-validate) from glib, which returns:

- true/false
- the location of the last valid data that was read from the string

Is there a posibility to ge beyond this, and also get the valid data after the non-utf8 portion? Example:

```cpp
std::string invalid = "okdata\xa0\xa1morevalid";
```

Currenlty I am able to save "okdata" but I would like to get "okdatamorevalid".

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Since the invalid data is not UTF-8, you cannot make assumptions about its length and must skip it one byte at a time unfortunately - unless you know something about the cause of the malformed data which you didn't tell us. However, you could implement the "scanning for next valid byte" yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep calling `g_utf8_validate` on the remaining string (skipping the first byte every time) to find more valid sections:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <glib.h>

int main() {
  char const *data = "okdata\xa0\xa1morevalid";
  std::string s;

  // Under the assumption that the string is null-terminated.
  // Otherwise you'll have to know the length in advance, pass it to
  // g_utf8_validate and reduce it by (pend - p) every iteration. The
  // loop condition would then be remaining_size > 0 instead of *pend != '\0'.
  for(char const *p = data, *pend = data; *pend != '\0'; p = pend + 1) {
    g_utf8_validate(p, -1, &pend);
    s.append(p, pend);
  }

  std::cout << s << std::endl; // prints "okdatamorevalid"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am making sure that it is null-terminated by using c_str which, as I have read, guarantees this, as: 


`const char* toFilter = inputString.c_str();`

Comment: It does, yes. If you don't want to embed null bytes in your text, you can use the above unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it in a loop.  Something like this:

```
std::string sanitize_utf8(const std::string &in) {
    std::string result;
    const char *ptr = in.data(), *end = ptr + in.size();
    while (true) {
        const char *ptr2;
        g_utf8_validate(ptr, end - ptr, &ptr2);
        result.append(ptr, ptr2);
        if (ptr2 == end)
            break;
        ptr = ptr2 + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```